# A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column 'Id' in TPT inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

I'm using EF code first, I have following entities:

[image]

I'm using `TPT` method for inheritance, to create one-to-one or zero relation, wrote following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.ProductionInstruction)
                .WithRequired(x => x.Order);
}
```

I write following code to save a `ProductionInstruction`:

```
var pi = new ProductionInstruction();
/* set pi properties */
ctx.ProductionInstructions.Add(pi);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I get following error when `ctx.SaveChanges()` run:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.

Is there any way to implement 1..0-1 between my two entities, without above error?

Comment: And is there a link to an Order in `/* set pi properties */` ? There should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Entity Framework, a one-to-one mapping with a required principal is implemented by giving the dependent a primary key that's also a foreign key to the principal. The dependent copies its primary key from the principal.

In your case, EF wants `ProductionInstruction.Id` to be a foreign key to `Order.Id`, and its value should be copied from the `Order` it belongs to. However, because of the inheritance, `ProductionInstruction.Id` is an identity column (*store-generated*), so it can't be set in code.

You either have to remove the inheritance, so `ProductionInstruction.Id` can be mapped as not store-generated, or change the mapping to optional on both sides. The latter will give `ProductionInstruction` a separate foreign key to `Order`.

Comment: In your 2nd solution, do you mean I use `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.ProductionInstruction)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Order)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.